# Banned from flagging, even though flag turned out to be useful

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, migration, flag-ban

I flagged a question, because it should have been moved to Code Review. My flag was declined, but then the question was moved to Code Review. How come I am still banned from flagging if the flag turned out useful?

This is the post that led to the ban:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79684/federal-and-state-income-tax-calculator

Comment: You probably have many declined flags.

Comment: You have two declined flags on that question contributing to the ban. I was not the one who handled the flags, but I'm guessing miscommunication.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question and the flags were a bit of a mess but here is what happened.

There were three flags on the post requesting that this question be migrated to Code Review.  I declined flags and performed some comment clean-up telling the user to post the question on Code Review.

My reasons for declining the flags were:

1. I didn't think it was a great question that was worthy of being migrated
2. The question had a few answers, none of which appeared to be Code Review worthy answers.

A few hours later we received another flag requesting that this be migrated to Code Review. That flag was declined by another moderator.

Later, a Code Review mod, brought to our attention that the user cross-posted the question, this happened because the user was told to post on Code Review via the comments. Now, we had 2 questions on multiple sites and the SO version was on the way to being closed, so we migrated the question so it could be merged.

You wound up with a flag ban because you flagged the question twice for migration and we didn't feel it was a good candidate to be migrated - unfortunately, you have a small flag history with 2 flags declined in a short timespan, this resulted in your ban.