# A mechanism by which flags can become "undeclined"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, declined-flags, moderation

Originally, I came here to rant following a buildup of frustration at the fact that some 40% of my declined flags are on posts that were later deleted by either [another moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25425071/3372061) or [through the review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43215259/3372061) (or maybe regular del-votes, though unlikely). So I looked around and found these Q&A:

1. [Why was a proper flag declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344790).
2. [Can a declined flag be made helpful flag later by Moderator?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343466).
3. [Banned from flagging, even though flag turned out to be useful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285509).
4. [When a flag is declined, then the post is deleted/closed later, auto review the flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288201).

Which lead to the following conclusion:

> With the current system, in case of disagreement between a ♦ and the community, two ♦s, or if a ♦ makes a mistake - a **legitimate** (albeit *controversial*) flag ends up "penalizing" its submitter.

There is little justice in this, and yet moderators cannot modify the majority of flags once a decision has been made.

Thus, **my suggestion is** to introduce a system whereby moderators *could* "upgrade" certain declined/rejected flags to "disputed", "helpful" or some other class created specifically for this scenario (i.e. if the flagging reason was invalid, but there was something else wrong with the post). It doesn't matter - as long as the flags are no longer counted as "unhelpful" - as they *did* bring attention to the post, and said post *was* closed/deleted as consequence (even if the flag wasn't 100% spot-on).

Perhaps in the future, an automatic mechanism would be created to address these cases.

---

P.S.

This question might be considered a duplicate of *4.* above, yet the [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) was neither accepted nor rejected.

Comment: How exactly did you flag those two examples?

Comment: so you flag a post for the wrong reason (maybe "spam") and it is deleted for another reason, you want the system (or a mod) to be able to manually change the "decline" to "helpful"?

Comment: @RobertLongson - (respectively) VLQ, NAA. psubsee2003 - not necessarily to "helpful", at the very least to "disputed". My main concern are questions deleted for the same reason as the flag (I consider NAA/VLQ the same for this purpose).

Comment: If you have to express your declined flags as a percentage I assume you have a bigger problem. How many declined flags (a number) do you have?

Comment: somewhat related: [Reason for flags declined?](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3356/97481) ("flag decisions were reversed..."), [My “not an answer” flag is gone and not showing in my history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110016/165773)

Comment: [It's already possible to change a flag from declined to disputed.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342855/4751173)

Comment: @Glorfindel That's only possible with spam/offensive flags, and the tool was only added because those flags have hefty penalties for the user that need to be able to be cleared in case of an error. The change to disputed is only a side-effect necessary to remove the penalties. It's not meant to be used for clearing old decisions, and moderators *should not* be using it for such a situation.

Comment: @rene I was talking about percentage that expresses "declined-but-helpful out of total declined".. I only have 10 total declined flags :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get that users like to have a nice flag record, but your flag record really isn't all that important. At least, not important enough to warrant anything like this. Moderators have enough *active* flags to handle without the added stress of having to review past decisions for accuracy too. Doing anything with already-handled flags is... a complete waste of time.

If your flag brought attention to the post that resulted in some action, great. If it didn't result in action, there are ways of getting a second look. But we're not gonna have moderators going back to evaluate old flags so they can potentially change their outcome, and it's extremely unlikely we'll ever implement tools that let them change the outcome of a flag in general.

As mentioned in the comments, moderators *can* clear spam/offensive flags of a post, which inherently changes the flag to disputed as well. However, this tool was created so that moderators could reverse the -100 rep penalties for users in case of errors. This tool is *not* meant to be used to fix declined flag errors and moderators should not be bothering themselves with that task.

Comment: Thank you. Let me clarify - I wasn't necessarily talking about another review queue for mods (that would likely be an overkill), just a _permission_ to change the status of flags besides "spam", should they come across a situation that warrants it. I conclude that an automatic "disputing of rejected-but-acted-upon flags" system makes _more_ sense than having the mods review old rejections. As you imply, at the end of the day this has little actual impact on a person with a vast majority of helpful flags, besides their own feeling. And yet, "feeling" is important for continued participation...